# Diseño de base de datos

Tags: sql, diseño

necesito de su ayuda, estoy diseñando una base de datos para el control de alumnos por parte de un maestro.

El diseño que les muestro en la imagen va asi, un maestro puede tener uno o mas establecimientos y cada establecimiento puede tener uno mas grados, cada grado puede tener varios cursos y tambien varios alumnos, hasta alli me parece todo bien.

Pero si quiero por ejemplo que se guarde las notas de tareas para cada alumno y que cada tarea pertenece a algun curso, alli genero una relacion circular y no se de que otra manera plantearlo, como puedo resolverlo?

espero puedan ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa, por curiosidad ¿eres Samotracio?

Comment: grados - cursos - estudiantes - tareas

Comment: mmm no se que es samatracio. Ahora bien, esa relación no funcionaria bien, porque tendria que existir un registro por curso para cada estudiante, se repetiría la información innecesariamente, pero gracias por el comentario, ya lo había considerado.

Comment: disculpa, ese nick (samo - samotracio) era de un conocido de mi ciudad, me pareció curioso y ya te iba a preguntar por las amistades :D

Comment: aaah bueno >D pero no, no hay relación.

Answer (score 0):

No es ningún problema. Es lógico que haya alumnos en cada grado y que los alumnos tengan tareas y que esas tareas pertenezcan a un curso y el curso a un grado.

Ahora, yo te recomiendo una tabla mas. Tengo un cuaderno del profesor que utilizan en varios centros y en esa relación hecho de menos las matriculaciones.

Una cosa es el concepto de curso, y otra el de matriculación. La matriculación es que un alumno se dé de alta en un curso concreto (que en mi caso, son asignaturas y no cursos, pero supongo que en tu caso te valdrá con cursos).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, en mi caso, los alumnos no se matriculan a un curso, van en un grado y llevan todos los cursos de ese grado. En cuanto a tu sugerencia, pordrías explicar un poco mas detallado como usar esa otra tabla?

Comment: Una tabla estudiantes cursos con idestudiante, idgrado e idcurso. Aunque no cumpla las directrices de diseño mas puristas es muy práctica.

Comment: Muchas gracias Iker, lo voy a hacer de esa manera, haber que tal me queda. Saludos.